# Исключение при наведении на кнопку

Tags: исключения, многопоточность, c#

Доброго времени суток!

Уважаемые программисты, сколько раз вы меня уже выручали... И тут снова требуется помощь. Пишу свой компонент, где есть две кнопки. Кнопки нужно убрать либо анимированно, либо моментально. На это есть своя функция с обработчиками. Вычисления и функционал правильные. Так как на убирание анимированным способом требуется время, нужно анимацию кнопок в поток засунуть (необходимо).

Оформлял вроде все верно, но проблема такая:
при компиляции и наведении на кнопку (прикрепил обработчик) вылетает исключение, которое я не пойму, как обойти...

[image: эксепшн]

По трассировке данная функция запускается впервые. Помогите пожалуйста. Заранее благодарен!

**UPD**

Функционал:

```
void LeftButtonAction(bool animate, btAction action)
{
    if (action == btAction.Show) btLeftHidden = false;
    else btLeftHidden = true;

    btLeftThread = new Thread(delegate() { ButtonCallAction(btLeft, animate, action); });
    btLeftThread.Start();
    btLeftThread.Join();
}
void RigthButtonAction(bool animate, btAction action)
{
    if (action == btAction.Show) btRigthHidden = false;
    else btRigthHidden = true;

    btRigthThread = new Thread(delegate() { ButtonCallAction(btRigth, animate, action); });
    btRigthThread.Start();
    btRigthThread.Join();
}
void ButtonCallAction(Button _bt, bool animate, btAction action)
{
    lock (lockerLeft)
    {
        switch (action)
        {
            case btAction.Hide:
                {
                    if (animate)
                    {
                        for (byte i = 0; i < _bt.Width; i += (byte)btnsShowAndHideMovementSpeed)
                        {
                            _bt.Location = new Point(_bt.Location.X - btnsShowAndHideMovementSpeed, _bt.Location.Y);
                            this.ItemsPanel.Refresh();
                            Delay(btnsShowAndHideTimeSpeed);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _bt.Location = new Point(-10, _bt.Location.Y);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            case btAction.Show:
                {
                    if (animate)
                    {
                        for (byte i = 0; i < _bt.Width; i += (byte)btnsShowAndHideMovementSpeed)
                        {
                            _bt.Location = new Point(_bt.Location.X + btnsShowAndHideMovementSpeed, _bt.Location.Y);
                            this.ItemsPanel.Refresh();
                            Delay(btnsShowAndHideTimeSpeed);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _bt.Location = new Point(0, _bt.Location.Y);
                    }
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
}

void Delay(int ms)
{
    DateTime timestart = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime timecount;
    TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.Zero;
    while (span.Milliseconds < ms)
    {
        timecount = DateTime.Now;
        span = timecount - timestart;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прямое обращение к элементам управления допустимо только из того потока, в котором они были созданы. Для обращения из другого потока используйте метод контрола Invoke. В этот метод нужно передать делегат, который выполнится в потоке контрола.

Comment: Спасибо) плюсую!

Comment: В пятом дотнете всё будет автоматически разруливаться через async / await.

Answer (score 1):

[Control.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx):

> Выполняет делегат асинхронно в потоке, в котором был создан базовый дескриптор элемента управления.

Comment: Спасибо) плюсую!